# opencv maximum "differentation" pseudocolor table

Tags: algorithm, opencv

I'm looking for an algorithm to create a table of false color. Of course we can use something like

```
void ImgCoreQCV::GeneratePseudocolorTab(vector<Vec3b> &vec, int iNColor)
{
   for(int i=0; i<iNColor; i++){
        int b = theRNG().uniform(0, 255);
        int g = theRNG().uniform(0, 255);
        int r = theRNG().uniform(0, 255);

    /*int b = rand()&255;
    int r = rand()&255;
    int g = rand()&255;*/

    vec.push_back(Vec3b((uchar)b, (uchar)g, (uchar)r));
    }
}
```

but often generated color are very similar. Perhaps there is an algorithm in which the difference between the perception of colors is maximum?

Comment: Is it a [colormap](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d50/group__imgproc__colormap.html) you are looking for?

Comment: @Catree I think the actual problem is a way to decide which colors to add to the colormap so that they're all distinguishable from each other.